# Xamarin, App ends when finish() is called in the second activity

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin, xamarin.android

In MainActivity : Am starting a new Activity for result to return an Image //nothing wrong here

```
Action2.Click += delegate {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this , typeof(Camera));
            StartActivityForResult(intent, 12121);
        };
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            if (requestCode == 12121 && resultCode == Result.Ok )
            {
                var bytearray = data.GetByteArrayExtra("Image");
                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
                _Image.SetImageBitmap(image);
            }
```

In Second Activity : //This Activity supposed to get an Image and return it to the MainActivity But the app close/ends when finish() is called !

```
[Activity(Label = "Camera")]
    public class Camera : Activity
    {
        TextureView mTextureView;
        Camera2Simplified Cam;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Camera);
            TextView Cameralog = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.CameraLog);
            mTextureView = FindViewById<TextureView>(Resource.Id.textureView);
            Button Capture = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Capture);
            Cam = new Camera2Simplified(this, mTextureView);
            Capture.Click += delegate {
                if (Cam.Capture())
                {
                    var buffer = Cam.mImage.GetPlanes()[0].Buffer;
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.Capacity()];
                    buffer.Get(bytes);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this,typeof(MainActivity));
                    intent.PutExtra("Image", bytes);
                    SetResult(Result.Ok,intent);
                    Finish();
                }
            };
        }   
        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            Cam.OnResume();
        }
        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause();
            Cam.OnPause();
        }
    }
}
```

In "Camera2Simplified" class the app use Camera2 API to connect to Hardware and show the preview on the passed texture , Button Capture an Image which is not null, Any thoughts on why the app crash/end/close when finish(); is called ? is there a missing flag or something ?

> Note : when I comment out the OnResume() OnPause(); the app doesn't
>   connect to the hardware and no preview is made,In this case I tried to SetReusult()
>   with both Results.Cancelled and Results.OK and the App worked just fine > > returned to the
>   MainActivity normally.

Comment: You should provide some code and error message.

Comment: Just from what I can see, I think you have called finish(); in your first activity after you started the second activity !!

Comment: @Nemus There is no error message, the code runs perfect, but since I overridden OnResum withing the second activity, calling finish() is ending the whole app instead of ending the second Activity .

Comment: @JaswanthManigundan, no at all, it's right after SetResults , in the second activity , when I comment out OnResume and OnPause , the Activities switch normally

Comment: @JohnJoe Xamarin use Finish , every command starts with capital unlike android studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first off, if you want to clean up that activity when you call the new intent, I would advise using an activity flag on the calling activities intent, rather than finish, nohistory would probably be best.

Secondly, it is unclear what exactly is causing your error because we have no idea what the activity that the intent loads is doing, for all we know you could be doing something that causes the app to close in the activity the intent loads, but we would have no idea. Try adding flags to the intent and see if that helps, maybe NewTask or something and just see if anything changes. If you want more info than this, provide us with more code, when it comes to Xamarin, don't be afraid to share a lot of code, in some technologies it's overkill, with Xamarin it usually only helps to have more code to look at.

Comment: Am lunching hardware connection (camera) and using Camera Api 2 in the second activity 
when the Image is ready am trying to pass it back to the MainActivity and here the app close after using finish() I tried flags didn't work but now am reading more about flags, hopefully it would lead to fix this weird problem